# Как вывести одно и тоже свойство (name(b)) несколько раз на форме

Tags: lsfusion

Получилось сделать только объявив еще одно свойство `name2(b) = name(b)`, которое можно потом добавить на форму. Но то работает только для определенного свойства, в данном случае `name` определенного класса.

Answer (score 1):

Свойство можно добавить на форму произвольное число раз, но при этом каждому *свойству на форме* нужно дать уникальное имя. Это можно сделать с помощью явного указания имени:

```
PROPERTIES name1 = name(b), name2 = name(b)
```

В данном примере можно обойтись и явным указанием только одного имени

```
PROPERTIES name(b), othername = name(b)
```

Суть в том, что каждое добавленное свойство на форме должно иметь уникальное имя в пределах формы. При добавлении свойства без явного указания имени в виде `name(b)`, имя создаваемого свойства на форме будет таким же: `name(b)`, поэтому когда в форму добавляется два раза одно и то же свойство, то создаются два свойства на форме с одинаковым именем и происходит конфликт.

> Получилось сделать только объявив еще одно свойство

Минус такого решения в том, что в данном случае создается лишнее свойство, а это ненужные накладные расходы, как на уровне кода (дополнительная строка кода, дополнительное имя в пространстве имен), так и во время выполнения (как минимум дополнительный объект в памяти,
дополнительный объект в базе данных).